# What could be a single word or phrase for the one who helps people to achieve their goals?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, meaning-in-context

I was just wondering about this word to suggest it to my friend to use it for the NGO he is going to start soon.

Comment: We often use "***coach***" in this context, but you'll have to give us more background and examples if you want better tailored answers.

Comment: I think the concept you are trying to put into words is way too vague. Remember, both Alfred and Robin helped Batman achieve his goals, so `butler` and `sidekick` could be correctly applied there.

Answer (score 13):

So, there are plenty of words available to accomplish this aim, however you should use them in the proper situation. I mention some of them here (please note that some of these words have other meanings too, but I just focus on the related meaning here):

**Coach**: Someone who trains a person or team in a sport.
e.g.: A tennis coach.

**Lecturer**: Someone who gives lectures, especially in a university.
e.g.: She's a brilliant lecturer.

**Instructor**: Someone who teaches .
e.g.: A driving instructor.

**Trainer**: Someone who teaches people particular skills, especially the skills they need to do a job.
e.g.: A teacher trainer.

**Governess**: A woman who lived with a family and taught their children in past times.
e.g.: As a governess, Charlotte Brontë received twenty pounds a year.

**Educator**: (formal) Someone whose job involves teaching people, or someone who is an expert on education.
e.g.: Most educators agree that class sizes are still too big.

**Mentor**: An experienced person who advises and helps a less experienced person.
e.g.: Auden later became a friend an mentor.

**Professor**: A teacher in a college or university. In Britain, a professor is a high-ranking university teacher, especially one who is head of a department.
e.g.: She was professor of linguistics at Cambridge University.

**Leader**: The person who directs or controls a group, organization, country, etc.
e.g.: The leader of the local black community.

**Guide**: Someone whose job is to take tourists to a place and show them around.
e.g.: A tour guide.

**Guru**: Someone who knows a lot about a particular subject, and gives advise to other people.
e.g.: A management guru.

**Counsellor/counselor**: Someone whose job is to help and support people with problems.
e.g.: Are you seeing a counsellor?

**Consultant**: Someone whose job is to advice on a particular subject.
e.g.: A management consultant.

All the meaning and examples borrowed from the Longman dictionary.

Comment: Some of these are mixed up, like the two Lecturers and Coach, and the Mentor description.

Answer (score 10):

I would say facilitator or guide.

Answer (score 5):

The first word to my mind is mentor:

> -- an experienced and trusted adviser.

Answer (score 5):

Enabler, one who enables.  Not commonly used in British English.
It can also have negative connotations, meaning someone who allows an addict to keep up his addictive habit.  (ref psychcentral.com, wikipedia.com )

Comment: I am surprised by your comment, I hear this used a lot in British English.

Answer (score 1):

How about [*guide*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guide)?

Especially if "your goal" is a literal mountain peak.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Granada, Nicaragua.  When we got our residency, we got help from a professional local who knows the ropes.  He is referred to as an 'expeditor'.